# Creating a new user in the mysql Command line interface

Tags: mysql, bash

I went inside the mysql CLI in Bash via:

mysql -u root -p

I then tried to create a new user limited to localhost, with this following command, which was failed:

```
create user "${domain}"@"localhost" identified by -p;
```

Why was the command failed?

Edit: My aim is to create (or paste) the user's password in command execution (this is why I left `-p` empty. The code is part of a greater script file and I don't want to expose any password in that file.

Comment: -p is your password?

Comment: Of course not... I wanted to create here in place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way to create a user for localhost:

```
CREATE USER 'myuserinlocalhost'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwordinlocalhost';
```

Here is how it can look like with PDO:

```
$sql = "CREATE USER '?'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ?";
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $data = array($user,$password);
    $statement->execute($data);
```

Comment: So the password must be changed after creation?

Comment: My aim is to create it in execution.

Comment: No, you don't have to change the password. You set the password right here [ code]IDENTIFIED BY 'youruserpassword'[code]

Comment: Hmm, but this is part of a script file... I don't want the password to be exposed in that script file.

Comment: Offcourse not. You will handle the query probably with some library and you will set the password through some variable. So. this will look like: IDENTIFIED BY  $variable

Comment: I will show how exactly that can look like in new answer